# How to ping the server in Android?

Tags: android, connection, boolean, ping

How can I ping some web server in Android to test if I've Internet connection?
So I need the method which pings the given site and returns false if I've no Internet and true if I have.

Comment: Have you looked at the ConnectivityManager class? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Comment: Now I'm seeing it. 
Is this 
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) 
 {
     return ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
 }

a suitable solution for all situations and works fine?

Answer (score 12):

See this method, it's the best way to check for connectivity to a given server:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)

Comment: Yes, but specifically on Android it works - I have in production code and there are no issues with it. You should use it to check for connectivity to a given server, if you need general test for network connectivity, use ConnectivityManager

Comment: this way doesnot work, i find that it needs root privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Use these methods to ping the server

```
public static void inSomeWhere()
    {
        String pingResult = getPingResult("168.126.63.1");
        boolean isNetOk = true;
        if (pingResult == null) {
            // not reachable!!!!!
            isNetOk = false;
        }

    }


    public static String getPingResult(String a) {
        String str = "";
        String result = "";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = r.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 3 " + a);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            int i;

            while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
                output.append(buffer, 0, i);


            str = output.toString();

            final String[] b = str.split("---");
            final String[] c = b[2].split("rtt");

            if (b.length == 0 || c.length == 0)
                return null;

            if(b.length == 1 || c.length == 1)
                return null;

            result = b[1].substring(1, b[1].length()) + c[0] + c[1].substring(1, c[1].length());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(reader != null)
            {
                try{reader.close();}catch(IOException ie){}
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```