# Ping Permission denied

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

When I try to ping a device from my MAUI App built for Android I get a SocketException(Permission Denied). When i build for Windows it works just fine.

I can not find any Permission other than the ones I already have that could be required. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Tested with Android 11 and Android 12 on physical devices.

EDIT:
Network-connection works fine through HttpClient.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Code:

```
  var sender = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
  var options = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions();

  options.DontFragment = true;

  string data = "testdata";
  byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

  int timeout = 100;

  PingReply reply = sender.Send(address, timeout, buffer, options);
```

Exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException 'Permission denied'
```

Comment: maybe duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493010/how-to-ping-the-server-in-android)

Comment: @MarcoBeninca They are not really related. That question is how to ping in general. My question is about a specific implementation in a completely different technology.